In Django, why is my JSONFormField generating a style 'display: none'?
I am using django_jsonform (2.22.0) with django (4.2.11) to edit a configuration file written in JSON. I have verified the schema is correct and I can use it with the playground (https://bhch.github.io/react-json-form/playground/). When I generate the form, I print the form output and it has 'style "display: none"' embedded in it.
from pathlib import Path
from django import forms
from django_jsonform.forms.fields import JSONFormField

from testsite import settings


def loadSchema():
    with open(Path(settings.CONFIG_ROOT) / 'config2.schema.json') as configFile:
        return json.load(configFile)


class ConfigurationForm(forms.Form):

    configuration = JSONFormField(schema=loadSchema())

def configuration(request: Request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConfigurationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        with open(Path(settings.CONFIG_ROOT) / 'config.json') as configFile:
            data = json.load(configFile)
        form = ConfigurationForm(initial={'configuration': data})
        print(f'form data = {form}')

    return render(request,
                  "admin/preferences/preferences.html",
                  context={"form": form})

The print(f'form data = {form}') statment produces output that has both the correct data and schema embedded:
form data = <tr>
    <th><label for="id_configuration">Configuration:</label></th>
    <td>
      
      <div data-django-jsonform-container="true"  class="django-jsonform-container"></div>

<textarea cols="40" id="id_configuration" name="configuration" rows="10"  style="display: none;" data-django-jsonform="{&quot;data&quot;: &quot;{

<!-- sensitive data removed -->

}&quot;, &quot;schema&quot;: {&quot;title&quot;: &quot;MICE Server Configuration Specification&quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MICE Server Configuration&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;waba&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;WABA server setting&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {}, &quot;additionalProperties&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;Facility server settings&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: [&quot;url&quot;, &quot;username&quot;, &quot;password&quot;], &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;url&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The URL of the WABA server&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}, &quot;username&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The username to log in to the WABA server&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 32}, &quot;password&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The password to log in to the WABA server&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 32}}}}, &quot;session_cookie_age&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The maximum session age in seconds&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Session Cookie Age&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;integer&quot;, &quot;default&quot;: 360}, &quot;databases&quot;: {&quot;tile&quot;: &quot;Database configuration parameters&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: [&quot;default&quot;], &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;default&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: [&quot;engine&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;user&quot;, &quot;password&quot;, &quot;host&quot;], &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;engine&quot;: {&quot;title&quot;: &quot;Engine&quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;Database engine specification&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 48}, &quot;name&quot;: {&quot;description&quot;: &quot;The database name&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;default&quot;: &quot;mice&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 16}, &quot;user&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The username to log in to the database&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}, &quot;password&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The password to log in to the database&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 32}, &quot;host&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;The name of the database&#x27;s host&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;default&quot;: &quot;localhost&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}, &quot;options&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;Options for the database&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {}, &quot;additionalProperties&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;}}}}}}, &quot;oidc&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;OIDC Authentication Settings&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: [&quot;client_id&quot;, &quot;client_secret&quot;], &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;client_id&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;OIDC Client ID&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}, &quot;client_secret&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;OIDC Client Secret&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}}}, &quot;azure&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;Azure settings&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;dict&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: [&quot;tenant_id&quot;, &quot;uri&quot;], &quot;keys&quot;: {&quot;tenant_id&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;Azure Tenant ID&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}, &quot;uri&quot;: {&quot;help_text&quot;: &quot;Azure ID&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;maxLength&quot;: 64}}}}}, &quot;fileHandler&quot;: &quot;&quot;, &quot;fileHandlerArgs&quot;: {&quot;field_name&quot;: &quot;configuration&quot;, &quot;model_name&quot;: &quot;&quot;}, &quot;errorMap&quot;: {}, &quot;validateOnSubmit&quot;: false, &quot;readonly&quot;: false}"></textarea>

      
      
        
      
    </td>
  </tr>

Notice that the TextArea has style="display: none;". Why does it do that? And why is the field blank if I coerce the style to display: block;?
So what am I doing wrong?

The textarea is kept hidden by django-jsonform because that's where it stores the "raw" json data. A user-friendly dynamic form is rendered via javascript inside the django-jsonform-container html div.
